# How to prevent data binding on a specific Domain Class in Grails?

Tags: grails, data-binding

I've read the grails documentation about data binding and saw we can define which property of a class is bindable or not by defining the bindable constraint.

So I have some domain classes extending from a Validator class and I would like to use data binding on the properties of these classes, but deny databinding on every property of the Validator class.

Does Grails provide a way to forbid databinding on every property on a Class level?

Comment: Lookup importFrom  https://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/guide/validation.html  If you want more control over which constraints are imported, use the include and exclude arguments. Both of these accept a list of simple or regular expression strings that are matched against the property names in the source constraints. So for example, if you only wanted to import the 'lastName' constraint you would use:

Comment: @vahid Thanks for replying. I get the idea,